# Remove a group of textbox with java script

Tags: javascript

I want to remove a group of textbox that their name are textbox1.

How can I do it?

My code doesn't work.

```
function remove_textbox(){
var parent=document.getElementById("div1");
var child=document.getElementsByName("textbox1");
parent.removeChild(child);            
}
```

Any help?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show us your relevant html code?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function remove_textbox(){
    var parent = document.getElementById("div1");
    var child = document.getElementsByClassName("textbox1")[0];
    parent.removeChild(child);
}

remove_textbox();
```

Comment: Thank you - Thank you - Thank you
:)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `parent` really is the direct parent of the boxes, you'd have to iterate and remove each one

```
function remove_textbox(){
    var parent   = document.getElementById("div1");
    var children = document.getElementsByName("textbox1");

    for( var i=children.length; i--; ) {
        parent.removeChild(children[i]);
    }
}
```

```js
function remove_textbox(){
    var parent   = document.getElementById("div1");
    var children = document.getElementsByName("textbox1");

    for( var i=children.length; i--; ) {
        parent.removeChild(children[i]);
    }
}

document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', remove_textbox)
```

```html
<div id="div1">
    <input type="text" name="textbox1">
    <input type="text" name="textbox1">
    <input type="text" name="textbox1">
    <br /><br />
    <button id="test">Remove inputs</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you - Thank you - Thank you
:)

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByName returns collection. So you need to remove these elements one by one.

```
function remove_textbox(){
    var parent=document.getElementById("div1");
    var children=document.getElementsByName("textbox1");
    var index;
    for (index = children.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
    parent.removeChild(children[index]);
    }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you - Thank you - Thank you
:)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function remove_textbox(){
  var parent=document.getElementById("div1");
  [].slice.call(document.getElementsByName("textbox1")).forEach(
    function (child) { parent.removeChild(child); } );
}

document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onclick = remove_textbox;
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <input name="textbox1">
  <input name="textbox1">
  <button>Remove</button>
</div>
```